# Performing Matrix Vector Product using Eigen library in C++

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-multiplication

How do I perform a **matrix vector product** using the `Eigen` library in C++ with a "for loop", when the date type of my variables are in the form `Eigen::MatrixXd` and `Eigen::VectorXd`?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use the in-built `* operator` of directly multiplying a matrix with vector, I want to use a for loop and perform the element wise operation myself

When I try to do the element wise multiplication on `Eigen::MatrixXd` and `Eigen::VectorXd`, I get an error.

Comment: what did you try and what did you get ? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75034336/edit) the question and write the code as well as the error that you got into the question as text.

Comment: This question needs improvement. Preferably by adding a code snippet of what you tried and the corresponding error messages that you get.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what problem you have encountered. Here is an example that may help.

```cpp
    // mat: 3x4 vec_h: 4x1
    Eigen::MatrixXd mat  = Eigen::MatrixXd::Ones(3,4);
    Eigen::VectorXd vec_h = Eigen::VectorXd::Random(4);

    // mat.row(i): 1x4
    // mat.row(i).transpose(): 4x1
    // cwiseProduct() element-wise multiplication
    // add .eval() because we are changing the element value in place.
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows(); ++i) {
        mat.row(i)=mat.row(i).transpose().cwiseProduct(vec_h).eval();
    }
```

In case you are looking for more information, here's the link [Eigen: The Array class and coefficient-wise operations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html)